# How can I convert a number to its English form in Perl?

Tags: perl, numbers, cpan, perl-module

I need a Perl script which takes numbers as input example 222
and it should output as **two hundred twenty two**.

Comment: Any time that you want to do something in Perl, start by [searching CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) for code that already does what you need. Most of the time CPAN already has it figured out for you.

Comment: and do not rely on any old code found on the web, it's often pretty bad

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use **[Lingua::EN::Numbers](http://search.cpan.org/~sburke/Lingua-EN-Numbers-1.01/lib/Lingua/EN/Numbers.pm)** - turn "407" into "four hundred and seven", etc.

```
use Lingua::EN::Numbers qw(num2en num2en_ordinal);

    my $x = 234;
    my $y = 54;
    print "You have ", num2en($x), " things to do today!\n";
    print "You will stop caring after the ", num2en_ordinal($y), ".\n";
```

prints:

```
You have two hundred and thirty-four things to do today!
You will stop caring after the fifty-fourth.
```

If you read the *documentation* of the module then you will find that the module also support the following things like,

- It can handle **integers** like "12" or "-3" and **real numbers** like "53.19".
- It also understands **exponential notation** -- it turns "4E9" into "four times ten to the ninth.
- It turns "INF", "-INF", "NaN" into "infinity", "negative infinity", and "not a number", respectively.

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 9):

[Number::Spell](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Number%3a%3aSpell) can help you:

```
use Number::Spell;
my $str = spell_number(222);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is one:

- [Number to Word Converter - Perl Engineering Project Download](http://www.fullinterview.com/final-year-projects/article/number-to-word-converter-perl-engineering-project-download-15750.html)

> Description: This basically converts a
>   number into words. It can only convert
>   numbers less than or equal of
>   novemdecillion quantity. It has a
>   complete input validation process.

Comment: Thanks for the link..it does the job, now I am going to learn the logic behind it :)

Comment: my guess the down vote is for not suggesting a CPAN module but instead old code of a very low quality: just skimming it shows the liberal use of goto, insane regexp to validate the input, no unwrapping of function arguments whatsoever... OTOH if the idea is to get someone asking for us to do their homework to get a bad grade, then that should do the trick.